# Cassandra 3.9, how to remote access

Tags: cassandra, port

i am new with cassandra. i just finish setup the cassandra 3.9 but don't know how to remote connect to that server.
the log show this : Starting listening for CQL clients on localhost/127.0.0.1:9042.i did try telnet to the server with LAN IP but unnable to telnet on that port

i did try change cassandra.yaml with LAN IP config ( listen_address: 192.168.3.36) but it will error then with messaging service :
 Starting Messaging Service on /192.168.3.36:7000 (eth0)
ERROR [main] 2016-11-22 16:43:04,286 CassandraDaemon.java:747 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690987/apache-cassandra-unable-to-gossip-with-any-seeds

Comment: i found the solution my changing the rpc_address